# Cascading Dropdownlist & ViewModel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, cascadingdropdown

I have the following models: `Department` (as city), `District` and `Store`.

`Department` has one to many `Districts`

`Districts` has one to many `Stores`

I'm constructing a view where I create a new Store and the user can choose the Department(city) and then the District dropdownlist updates instantly with the corresponding districts.

For this I created this ViewModel: StoreIndexData

```
public class StoreIndexData
{
    public Store Stores { get; set; }
    public Department Departments { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Controller where I populate the dropdownlist for the `Department`:

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        //Departaments List
        List<Department> Departmentlist = _context.Departments.ToList();
        Departmentlist.Insert(0, new Department { DepartmentID = 0,
                              DepartmentName = "Select" });

        ViewBag.DepartmentList = new SelectList(Departmentlist,
                                "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName");
        return View();
    }
```

And this is the View:

```
@model Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels.StoreIndexData

<form asp-action="Create">
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Store</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Departments.DepartmentID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="Departments.DepartmentID" 
             class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DepartmentList"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Stores.DistrictID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Stores.DistrictID, new SelectList(" "), "Select", new { @class = "form-control"})
        </div>
    </div>
```

And in the end of the view, this is my JS section:

```
@section Scripts {
<script src="~/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DepartmentID").change(function () {
            $.get("/Stores/GetDistrictList", { DepartmentID: $("#DepartmentID").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#DistrictID").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#DistrictID").append("<option value='" + row.DepartmentID + "'>" + row.DepartmentName + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

This section calls this action:

```
        public JsonResult GetDistrictList(int DepartmentID)
    {
        List<District> DistrictList = _context.Districts.Where(x => x.DepartmentID == DepartmentID).ToList();
        return Json(DistrictList);
    }
```

And that's it.

When I run the application, well, the District dropdownlist don't populate
**_Questions:**

- Is it possible that I can't access this properties inside the JScript `"#DepartmentID"` like this since I'm using a viewmodel? Maybe I need to change it to something like "#Departments.DepartmentID"?
- Could this work using a ViewModel? I'm not adding the Department property inside the Store model because it would be irrelevant since it gets its Department thru the District.
- I saw in the example that I followed that they added this line
  ProxyCreationEnabled = false
  Inside the JsonResult action. I didn't add it because I don't know what it does and don't know the consecuences in my application if I add it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,

**_Update**

I put a break point on this line, inside the JsonResult:

```
List<District> DistrictList = _context.Districts.
  Where(x => x.DepartmentID == DepartmentID).ToList();
```

But the application did not stopped there when I used the Department dropdownlist that is supossed to call that JsonResult. I believe the script section is what might be wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the javascript that gets the district list? My gut says that the get is being called but the path isn't resolving properly. I think you need to change the definition of the URL in $.get to @Url.Content("~/Stores/GetDistrictList").

Comment: I'm trying to debug that part but I'm getting the error "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.” when I put a break in the JS section and can't debug that part.

Comment: On another note, I believe $.get("/Stores/GetDistrictList") is a call to the Method GetDistrictList inside the Stores Controller, would that work with @Url? I know little of js  @Matt

Comment: You won't be able to debug it directly from Visual Studio like you can with the code behind. You'll need to open your browsers developer tools (usually F12) and set a breakpoint in there.

Comment: Using @Url in your javascript should work. I've done it before but I think I had to wrap it in a call to Html.Raw and Json.Encode like this @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Url.Content("~/Stores/GetDistrict"))). This is in your razor view so it will just resolve it to the correct URL and embed that in the script block in the cshtml file.